# App using flutter_inappwebview Crash after calling from out main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2 for implementation 3rd part payment gateway when I call the method from main.dart its running and working
but when I call it from other like cart.dart,checkout.dart, urwaypayment.dart The App crash immediately before Webview appear

this is the Calling method

```
result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute<String>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return new TransactPage(inURL: compURL);
            }));
```

and this error meassage

```
I/Dialog (30035): mIsSamsungBasicInteraction = false, isMetaDataInActivity = false
W/Gralloc4(30035): allocator 3.x is not supported
W/Gralloc3(30035): allocator 3.x is not supported
W/com.amart1.app(30035): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): Process: com.amart1.app, PID: 30035
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.(OkHttpClient.kt:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.(OkHttpClient.kt:204)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.InAppWebView.prepare(InAppWebView.java:184)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.FlutterWebView.(FlutterWebView.java:94)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.in_app_webview.FlutterWebViewFactory.create(FlutterWebViewFactory.java:26)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:186)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:708)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:422)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:285)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.(VirtualDisplayController.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createVirtualDisplayForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected Android API level 21+ but was 30
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$Companion.buildIfSupported(AndroidPlatform.kt:370)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.findPlatform(Platform.kt:204)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform$Companion.access$findPlatform(Platform.kt:178)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.(Platform.kt:179)
E/AndroidRuntime(30035): ... 24 more
I/Process (30035): Sending signal. PID: 30035 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```